# Validate Google Bot ip address on GAE standard

Tags: sockets, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, googlebot

I have a website built with a GAE 2nd gen Python 3 app.

Scrapers are scraping my website by forging the Google Bot user agent.  I'd like to validate the IP address of the scrapers so I can reject them but not reject real Google Bot traffic.

It seems that the best way to do this is with DNS lookups as [described here](https://blog.majsky.cz/detecting-google-bot-python-and-django/).  Doing DNS lookups, however, requires using `socket.gethostbyaddr` and `socket.gethostbyname` but sockets are not allowed in GAE standard.  I know that sockets are available with GAE flex but I can't switch to GAE flex.

Thanks to Steffen's comment I see that you can download the google bot IP addresses, but I don't want to have to track this and update my code when it changes.  The dynamic approach seems easier and safer.

Is it possible to dynamically validate that an IP address corresponds to the Google Bot in a GAE 2nd gen Python 3 app?

Comment: If you cannot do a dynamic lookup with DNS you need to do a static lookup using a predefined list. This list is just two clicks away from the article you linked to. Follow the link in "Google recommends to [verify its crawlers by performing DNS lookups](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553?hl=en)." and at the end of this article you'll find a link to the static  [list of Googlebot IP addresses](https://developers.google.com/search/apis/ipranges/googlebot.json).

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich, though I'd really prefer a dynamic lookup so I don't need to keep track of changes to googlebot IP addresses.

Comment: Anything dynamic requires that you'll be able to query some external source - which you can't do due to a lack of sockets.